# Saving to database via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a situation,I need to add lot of text to server (via ajax & php).Each is happeening by clicking on a add button.In order to reduce round trip.I am planning to give a save all button so once I store everything in client side and I can save all together to database via ajax so only one round trip.

I have 6 input fields and needs to save this info everytime

### My planning

Store everything in a JavaScript hidden variable and itreate this in php side and save it.
I will have to store lot of text in hiden field.Is my approach correct ? any better way ?

Comment: This approach sounds fine. Without further details thats all i can say

Comment: You can use the [local Storage Object of Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the data e.g. as a json-string and send this json to your server

Comment: hidden fields or javascript arrays ? which is good and easy and secure.

Comment: Have in mind that hidden-fields in HTML can be seen and (in the worst case) manipulated by the user

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to store it on hidden fields, just make a JSON object containing the data you want and then send it to the server throught ajax.

You can create the JSON object this way:

```
var jsonObject = {'name': $('#name').val(), 'city': $('#city').val()};
```

And then you send it to PHP throught AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'some.php',
    data: jsonObject,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function() {
    alert('success');
}).fail(function() {
    alert('error');
}).always(function() {
    alert('complete');
});
```

Comment: I would recommed to set the dataType option of ajax to json in this case

Comment: That depends on how the Server will return the data. But i agree with you, better to work with json-json format.